# A uniform random graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I am reading the  article [Rainbow trees in uniformly edge-colored graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.08315). But I encountered some difficulties and was puzzled.

There is a random graph $G(n,\omega(1)/n))$ and a color set $\mathcal{A}_1$ of size at least $n/2$.

The authors perform a random sparsification procedure of $G[X_1]$ as follows, where $X_1$ is a subset of vertex set of $G$:

1. Include each $e \in\left(\begin{array}{c}|X_i|\\ 2\end{array}\right)$ as an edge independently at random with probability $\omega(1) / n$.
2. If $e \in\left(\begin{array}{c}|X_i|\\ 2\end{array}\right)$ was included as an edge in Step (1), assign $e$ a color from $[n]$ uniformly at random.(Now, we have thm that a.a.s. $G[X_1]$ uses at least $n/4$ colors from $\mathcal{A}_1$ hold.)
3. For every $c \in \mathcal{A}_1$, let $E_c$ be the set of edges colored $c$. If $E_c \neq \emptyset$, choose a single member of $E_c$ uniformly at random, that is, with probability $1 /\left|E_c\right|$.
4. Discard all edges not chosen in Step (3). (This includes, in particular, all edges whose color is in $[n] \backslash \mathcal{A}_1$.)
5. From the remaining set of edges choose a subset of size $n / 4$ uniformly at random.

The authors say that the resulting graph distribution, which we denote by $\tilde{\mathbb{G}}_1$, coincides with the uniform graph distribution, namely $\mathbb{G}\left(|X_i|, n / 4\right)$, a uniform random graph. I don't understand this. It seems intuitively so, but I don't know the exact proof. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The procedure seems incompletely described. Suppose that in step 2, every single edge gets the same color $c$ (which happens with some positive, if very low, probability). Then in step 3, only one edge will be chosen, and in step 5, we will find it difficult to choose a subset of size $n/4$ of a $1$-element set. Are you sure you have included all the details?

Comment: I'm sure i have include all the details. I think the author is focusing on the asymptotic equivalence, that is, $n$ tends to $\infty$. So a.a.s.  every single edge gets the same color $c$ do not holds.

Comment: But if all we know about $|\mathcal A_1|$ is that it is at least $n/4$, then it is *not* a.a.s. true that at least $n/4$ colors will be used!

Comment: I added a thm that when you do the first two steps, a.a.s. $G[X_1]$ uses at least $n/4$ colors from $\mathcal{A}_1$ hold . It is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we condition on the event that $G[X_1]$ uses at least $n/4$ colors - which I assume is done in the paper, if not mentioned in the question - *then* any set of $n/4$ edges is equally likely to be chosen in step 5.

I think the quickest way to see this formally is to expose $G[X_1]$ and the random decisions made inside it in three phases:

1. First, expose only the *number* of edges chosen in step 1 from $G[X_1]$.
2. Second, expose the *number* of edges that get each color $c \in \mathcal A_1$ in step 2.
3. Third, expose everything else: *which* edges were chosen, *which* edges got which color, and *which* selections were made in steps 3 and 5.

Let $\mathcal E$ be the event that at least $n/4$ colors from $\mathcal A_1$ were used at least once. The important thing to note is that, conditioned on the outcome of phase 1, $\mathcal E$ is independent of phase 3. It is "phase 2-measurable". So conditioning on $\mathcal E$ (which we are told happens a.a.s.) is conditioning on what happens in phases 1-2.

Next, we can say that **conditioned on any single outcome of phases 1-2, each set of $n/4$ edges is equally likely to be chosen in step 5**. This is true just due to the fact that phases 1-2 never treat any elements of $\binom{X_1}{2}$ differently from any others. More formally: a permutation $\sigma$ of $\binom{X_1}{2}$ induces a bijection between phase-3 outcomes that lead to an $n/4$-element set $S \subset \binom{X_1}{2}$ being chosen, and phase-3 outcomes that lead to $\sigma(S)$ being chosen, so $S$ and $\sigma(S)$ must be equally likely. By varying $\sigma$, we can make $\sigma(S)$ be any $n/4$-element set we like.

By combining the statement in bold for all the outcomes of phases 1-2 where $\mathcal E$ occurs, we get the result we wanted: conditioned on $\mathcal E$, each set of $n/4$ edges is equally likely to be chosen in step 5.

(I would still be happier if we included a fictitious-continuation clause in the algorithm: if it turns out in step 5 that fewer than $n/4$ edges remain, disregard those remaining edges and just choose a set of $n/4$ edges from $\binom{X_1}{2}$ uniformly at random. Conditioning on $\mathcal E$, this fictitious continuation will never be used; but now we can say that $\tilde{\mathbb G}_1 \sim \mathbb G(|X_1|,n/4)$ in *every* outcome of phases 1-2, not just the outcomes where $\mathcal E$ occurs.)

Comment: Can i understand like this: the resulting graph obtained from the first $4$ steps can be regarded as a random graph $G(n,p)$ for some $p$. So, after the fifth step, we can say that it  is $G(n,n/4)$?

Comment: The graph after 4 steps does *not* have the $G(n,p)$ distribution; it is a $G(n,m)$ graph where $m$ itself is a random variable - $m$ is the number of colors that were used.

Comment: Each set of $n/4$ edges is equally likely to be chosen. However the edge set is chosen in graph $G(n,m)$, as you say. Why we have graph $G(n,n/4)$?

Comment: Are you asking me to write my answer again, but in a comment this time?

Comment: Please forgive my shallow knowledge. I think we obtain a graph from the graph from 2 steps in 3 and 4 steps. Why we have graph distribution $G(n,m)$ in 4 step?

Comment: Since $m$ is not a constant, all we're claiming is that each set of edges of a given size is equally likely to be chosen, since nothing we've done up until then cares about which edges are where.

Comment: G(n,m) is uniform random choosing a graph from all graphs with n vertices and m edges.  I understand each set of edges of a given size is uniform. However i can not understand that choosing a graph from all graphs with m edges.

Comment: I think what this says is that the answer to your question "Can I understand like this" is "No, that's not a helpful way for you to understand it."

Comment: Thank you very much. I seem to understand your answer. From the results,  each set of n/4 edges is equally likely to be chosen in step 5. Each set of n/4 edges means each set of n/4 edges in the complete graph, and equally likely means uniform random.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If we replace step $3$ choose a single edge of $E_c$ uniformly at random with choose a perfect matching of $E_c$ uniformly at random (suppose we can guarantee the existence of a perfect matching). What distribution does the resulting graph by new four steps obey?It seems difficult to characterize the new graph distribution.